# How can I restore my boot screen in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, boot, login, plymouth

I installed Kubuntu on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation... big mistake!

It has now changed my boot screen (boot prior to lightdm login screen)

How can I restore this back to Ubuntu login?

Nvidia drivers!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1989879

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Had to restart a couple of times, but all reset.

Comment: I did these changes and restarted my system (many times) but still the problem exists. I removed plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text and plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo packages as well. Now I am getting only purple screen (with no dots and no ubuntu image or text). I have ATI graphic card and using default graphic drivers. please help

Comment: After 5 days, all of a sudden it worked! Yeah true, had to restart a couple of times ;) Patience, huh :) But still wondering how did it work suddenly :P

Comment: Not sure if it worked bcz I have applied this fix as well

echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing a little easier

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can completely remove the Kubuntu Boot Screen by removing the `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo` and `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text` packages.

Type these in the terminal to remove those packages:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text
sudo apt-get --purge remove plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
```

Ignore it if the terminal can't find the `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text` package.

Answer (score 0):

These work for me:

```
sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep plymouth 
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```