# Ubuntu Desktop has changed appearance after installing tweak and Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, desktop-environments

I have a recent install of Ubuntu 14.04. I just installed a few things as recommended to do on howtoubuntu [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr), and on unixmen [here](http://www.unixmen.com/top-things-installing-ubuntu-14-1014-0413-1013-0412-1012-04/). As a consequence the appearance of my Ubuntu environment has changed, and when I start-up the desktop does not look the same, for example I cannot move around through workspaces and my background does not appear, both of these can be remedied by logging out and logging back in--but still general appearance has changed.

I thought the problem arose from `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop` so I did `sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop` but it is not back to the original fresh install Ubuntu desktop. I also installed Tweak among other things, as suggested in the above links, so it may not be GNOME related.

Noticeable problems are that when I reboot there is a footprint icon rather than the Ubuntu one. When I hit super the dash menu does not appear. The icons in the top right corner of my screen have changed too. As have the look of internet browsers and file windows, and files within windows and their ordering. Since removing GNOME, if I log out there is no drop down list to choose it but it still feels like GNOME is having influence. I attach a screenshot to give a feel for what my desktop now looks like. On the left-hand-side is a relevant section from my `.bash_history`.

[image: screenshot of desktop]

Comment: Log off. Check for foot (gnome icon) or screw. Click it; if your option is Gnome rather than Ubuntu, choose Ubuntu. that's how we move between desktop environments.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think I can do that though. "Since removing GNOME, if I log out there is no drop down list to choose it but it still feels like GNOME is having influence. "

Comment: The icons in the right hand side are changed because you are not using the correct Unity icons and themes perhaps. Make sure that you have theme selected Ambiance and icons Ubuntu-mono-dark.

Comment: That doesn't explain changed super key behaviour. Full install of Ubuntu suite is `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` though I doubt that'll help.

Comment: For the boot / logout screen maybe this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157349/how-can-i-restore-my-boot-screen-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: In general, I found that Unity (the default ubuntu desktop) and gnome do not play well together. They have a lot of common things with different defaults (for example, all the `dconf` settings)  that the tangle is difficult to solve. Try to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`, but I am not sure it can help.

Comment: thanks you for this advice. so `sudo apt-get reinstall ubuntu-desktop` would be the command?