# I see default Ubuntu Desktop changed after two other DE installed

Tags: themes, desktop-environments, pantheon, enlightenment

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572609/ubuntu-desktop-has-changed-appearance-after-installing-tweak-and-gnome) looks similar but that received no answers.

I installed two DE (enlightenment, pantheon) on Ubuntu. After that I see few differences on my default Desktop Environment.

I see colors of the windows has changed. Possibly, a good side effect is that it has become faster. 
Two Terminals appears in the application list.

Even two screenshot application.

[image: Duplicate applications]

Why it has happened? and do I have two applications or it is just customizations of same applications?

Comment: Installing multiple DE will duplicate applications as each DE comes with a window manager + a set of applications for text editing, music, perhaps disk burning, etc. I do not know why Ubuntu would be faster or the colors would change just due to multiple DE.

Comment: I think pantheon DE is conflicting with default DE. Reason for me thinking so is - pantheon's background image visible when I come back to wake my system up when it was in Default DE.

Answer (score -1):

Using multiple DE at the same time can cause conflicts... you can read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266224/will-i-have-problems-installing-multiple-desktop-environments/885872) to understand what I mean...

And the extra applications that you see after installation of the other DEs, they most possibly have come with the DE; a DE usually have some default bundle of programs/applications for various purposes. For example KDE has a bunch of applications installed by default- Ocular for reading Documents, Gwenview for viewing images and so on...

Comment: I am down voting this because although you may prefer not to install multiple DE for any variety of reasons,  and I understand those reasons, it really does not cause conflicts. The text editor of gnome does not conflict with the text editor of KDE, etc. I use multiple DE including gnome-shell, KDE, and Lxqt with no problems whatsoever. In the past I have included window managers such as fluxbox and openbox to the mix.

Comment: Please be sure to differentiate your preferences from bugs from actual conflicts. You prefer one DE, you prefer not to have multiple duplicate applications, etc. This is opposed to bug reports. Sure there may be an issue where you need to perform some post install configuration, such as setting a login manager, etc, or there may be a bug. But if you gave this advice based on bug reports you would not run any DE as they all have bug reports. Any potential conflict would be managed by apt in the dependencies of packages and any problem would be a bug report.

Comment: There is no intentional conflict between DE and just like in a perfect world there would be no bugs in gnome or kde there should also be no bugs or problems with multiple DE.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to uninstall default DE as doing so caused sleep-wakeup problem which is very irritating. I need to shutdown and restart again. I take this problem as a bug and now that I did something to it. I thought, if in any case, it is possible to do then I may have done it. So, I was checking.